# Uploading CSV File to Rails 4 DB via rake task

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rails-migrations

I am trying to import data from a csv fle using a rake task (rake data:import) and am getting errors. I have been teaching myself rails the past few months but after a day and a half of googling I found many solutions to this, none of which i could get to work.

Here is where I stand so far with my rake file:

```
require 'CSV'
namespace :data do
  desc "Import teams from csv file"
  task :import => [:environment] do
    file=IO.read('filepath of my csv').force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil)

    CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
      product.create ([
                       :name => row['name'],
                       :rating => row['rating'],
                       :year => row['year'],
                       :country => row['country'],
                       :state_or_province => row['state_or_province']]
                      )
    end

  end
end
```

I am not getting any specific error (as far as I can tell). The output which confuses me is:

```
tasks/dataimport.rake:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is that output indicative of anything specific going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a lot going wrong here so I'll start at the top.

[`CSV.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) is meant to open a file and iterate over it all at once. The first argument to `CSV.foreach` should be a file *name* not the file's *content*. That means that this:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
```

goes wrong because `file` is a string containing the CSV data rather than the file name that `CSV.foreach` expects. Since you're converting from Latin-1 text to UTF-8, you'll want to get `CSV.foreach` to deal with that for you and you can use the `:encoding` option for that:

> This method also understands an additional `:encoding` parameter that you can use to specify the Encoding of the data in the file to be read. [...] For example, `encoding: "UTF-32BE:UTF-8"` would read UTF-32BE data from the file but transcode it to UTF-8 before CSV parses it.

Putting that together, we have:

```
CSV.foreach('filepath of my csv', :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1:UTF-8') do |row|
```

Once you get the CSV reading and iteration going, you'll see errors like:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `product' for ...
```

You'd get a `NameError` because there is no `product` defined anywhere in your rake task. I suspect that you mean to say `Product.create`, that would try to create a new instance of your `Product` model. Ruby is case sensitive so `product` and `Product` are different things and `Product` would be the class.

Once the `NameError` is dealt with, you'll see complaints like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for [{ ... }]:Array
```

You'll get the `NoMethodError` because `Product.create` wants to see a Hash of attributes and their values, not an Array which contains a Hash. You would want to say:

```
Product.create(
  :name => row['name'],
  :rating => row['rating'],
  :year => row['year'],
  :country => row['country'],
  :state_or_province => row['state_or_province']
)
```

Of course, if your `row` contains only those five values, then just hand the whole `row` to `create`:

```
Product.create(row.to_hash)
```

and if `row` contains (or might contain) a bunch of other stuff that you don't want `create` to see, use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to grab just the part of `row` that you're interested in:

```
Product.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[name rating year country state_or_province]))
```

Note that `%w[...]` builds an array of strings from a white-space delimited list so these are the same:

```
%w[a b]
['a', 'b']
```

Then the splat (`*`) removes the array wrapper so these are the same:

```
row.to_hash.slice(*%w[name rating year country state_or_province])
row.to_hash.slice('name', 'rating', 'year', 'country', 'state_or_province')
```

You can use whichever form is easier on your eyes.

Also note the [`to_hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-to_hash) calls in there. Your `row` will be a `CSV::Row` object, calling `to_hash` on it will give you the row as a Hash.

---

That should leave your entire rake task looking like this:

```
CSV.foreach('filepath of my csv', :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1:UTF-8') do |row|
  Product.create(row.to_hash)
end
```

or

```
CSV.foreach('filepath of my csv', :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1:UTF-8') do |row|
  Product.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[name rating year country state_or_province]))
end
```

You might want to add some error handling to those `create` calls too.

Comment: Thanks! as soon as i get it working i will mark this as the asnwer. trying to figure out stringify_keys undefined method error now.

Comment: Do you have the full error about `stringify_keys`? Is it the `Product.create` complaining about something?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Very user-friendly explanation for someone who is new to rails. Thanks again!

Comment: code worked fine when i replaced row with each individual element in the row. the full error is undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<CSV::Row:0x00000101621a18>

Comment: Right, I forgot about the `CSV::Row` thing. You should be able to say `row.to_hash` instead of `row` to deal with that. I'll update my answer.