# Upload a CSV file from a local machine to heroku Rails app using Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

I've been trying to upload a big CSV file (1800 rows) from a local (the machine in my desk) CSV file to populate a table in Heroku postgresql, I've been reading some questions on stackoverflow but none solves my question i.e. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240297/uploading-csv-file-to-rails-4-db-via-rake-task) doesn't explain how to access the local file. The rake task I wrote works fine localy on development, I guess I can run the rake task using `heroku run bash` and then `rake import:family_data['tmp/storage/familias.csv']`, but I don't know how to specify the local file path... please help me.
This is the file I'm trying to upload:

```rb
id,name,description,discount,profit,created_at,updated_at
1,familia1,la familia uno,11.5,21.5,2024-01-17 13:00:00,2024-01-17 13:58:05
2,familia2,la familia dos,12.5,22.5,2024-01-17 13:00:00,2024-01-17 13:58:05
3,familia3,la familia tres,13.5,23.5,2024-01-17 13:00:00,2024-01-17 13:58:05
4,familia4,la familia cuatro,14.5,24.5,2024-01-17 13:00:00,2024-01-17 13:58:05
5,familia5,la familia cinco,15.5,25.5,2024-01-17 13:00:00,2024-01-17 13:58:05
```

I've tried with and without the id column, same result...
This is the rake task:

```rb
namespace :import do
  desc "Import Family Data"
  task :family_data, [:file_path] => :environment do |t, args|
    require "csv"
    puts "Importing Family Data"
    model = Family

    records = []
    CSV.foreach(args[:file_path], headers: true) do |row|
      records << model.new(row.to_hash)
    end
    puts "#{records.count} records to import"
    model.import!(records)
    puts "Imported #{model.count} #{model.name.pluralize}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `heroku run` command to run any rake task on heroku.
Please run below command

```
heroku run rake family_data['tmp/storage/familias.csv']
```

Here is [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake#:%7E:text=You%20can%20access%20the%20rake,up%2C%20run.) for it

Comment: I may have not been clear, that command you describe will look for the path 'tmp/storage/familias.csv' within the Heroku server space, not my local machine. What I need is to run the rake task that is already in the Heroky server space ACCESSING MY LOCAL MACHINE'S familias.csv file. I have read the Heroku documentation you point to

Comment: This is the output running the command you describe: ` $ heroku run rake import:family_data['tmp/storage/familias.csv']
Running rake import:family_data[tmp/storage/familias.csv] on ⬢ pruebacsv... up, run.7472 (Eco)
Importing Family Data
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/storage/familias.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
/app/lib/tasks/import.rake:14:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:108:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:108:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => import:family_data`

Comment: Are you still stuck on this issue?

Comment: Yes, I could not find a simple answer so I bought a computer and built a server on my own LAN...